# CruiseControl installation on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, cruisecontrol

So, can you tell me or give article about CruiseControl installation on FreeBSD?

Comment: What should we tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are still having the problem but it may help to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` using the command line option `-dashboardurl`.  See the [Standard Command Line Options](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/gettingstartedbindist.html#Command_Line_Options.Standard) page for more information.